# Django migrations, change parameter without losing data

Tags: django, python-3.x, миграция

Как мне изменить параметер для колонки, без потери даных?

```
 name = models.CharField(db_column='UserName', max_length=20,
                                     blank=True, null=True)
```

на

```
  name = models.CharField(db_column='UserName', max_length=100,
                                     blank=True, null=True)
```

нужно просто поменять `max_length` с 20 на **100**

Comment: Они и не потеряются. Почему бы данным потеряться?

Comment: если я меняю ```max_length``` с 20 на 100, джанго не видет изменений, если удалить поле, потом добавить, с новыми параметрами, даные потеряються правильно? или я ошибаюсь